# How do you pass deployment properties from a Stream - Spring Cloud Dataflow processor to a Task Launcher Dataflow to a composed task and child tasks

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

[image]

[image]

I have a SCDF Steam that consists of a HTTP Source - Custom Processor and Task Launcher Dataflow Sink. I am trying to pass properties from the processor to the task-launcher-dataflow and to child tasks. I have tried building the message to send to the task-launcher-dataflow in the processor that looks like the following...

```
{
"args":["--spring.profiles.active=prod","--dataflow-server-uri=http://spring-cloud-dataflow-server:8080"],
"name":"composedtask-filecopy2",
"deploymentProps":{"runID":"e6ac18d2-f53f-11eb-9a03-0242ac130003"}
}
```

The properties are making it to the composed task but not to the child tasks.

What is the format for the deployment properties to pass them along to the child tasks?

Answer (score 2):

The general procedure to pass application/deployer properties to child tasks in a Composed Task graph is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_passing_properties_to_the_child_tasks).

That said, the `tasklauncher-sink` is responsible for launching this graph on every upstream HTTP event in your use case. To pass deployer properties to child tasks in this method, you'll wrap the deployer properties with a similar composite prefix as the key, and along with the desired value.

For instance, if you want to pass the deployer property to `prescript` task in the graph, you may want to try:

> {
> "args":["--spring.profiles.active=prod","--dataflow-server-uri=http://spring-cloud-dataflow-server:8080"],
> "name":"composedtask-filecopy2",
> "deploymentProps":{"deployer.composedtask-filecopy2.prescript.memory":"2048m"}
> }

Comment: Thank you Sabby, this worked for getting properties to pass to the child tasks, I did run into another issue where the total character count of all of the properties I set is over 2500 and now i see a sql exception on the composed task pod. I was trying to shorten my properties by adding a wildcard ("deployer.composedtask-filecopy2.*.memory":"2048m") but this does not work, is there anyway to set global properties for all tasks in a composed task?

Comment: For 2.8.x.  try the format `deployer.*.local.java-cmd=java`

Comment: This initially appeared to work using the * to set properties for all of the sub tasks but after a reset of the scdf database it failed, had to go back and add individual properties for each sub task for this to work again.